# Simple code I can add to onStop, to stop GPS activity?

Tags: java, android, gps

Just like the title says, Is there a simple line of code I could add to `onStop()`that will simply stop any gps activity currently going on with my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unregister your receiver

Comment: I guess I should have explained in my first post. There is no receiver. I'm simply enabling geolocation access in a webview. That's all the code on my part. If what you're thinking was the case i'd know how to stop it. But since i'm not initiating it in my code thats why im looking for something like i described above

Comment: If you're just doing it in a webview, once the view goes away shouldn't it stop?

Comment: That's exactly how I figured it would work. But for some reason sometimes it stays on. Sort of annoying. I just figured there might be some code snippet out there for a simple check gps activity and if it's active stop it

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're doing, but if it's another controlling the gps in the webview it's really up to that app to stop it. If you post exactly what you're doing in your webview to do the gps i can help more maybe